# Sanity check the description of $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise C5.

> Describe $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$, as in part 4.
>
> Part 4: Explains why there are exactly four elements in
>   $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2 + x + 1\rangle$, lists the four elements, 
>   and gives their addition and multiplication tables.

Let $p(x)=x^3+x+1$.  The polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ as it has no root in $\Bbb{Z}_2$.

1. There is exactly a total of eight elements in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$,
   as that's the number of all the possible polynomials with degree less than the degree of $p(x)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$.
2. Specifically, these eight elements $\{0,1,x,x^2,1+x,1+x^2,x+x^2,1+x+x^2\}$ form a field which is isomorphic to the extended field $\Bbb{Z}_2(c)$, where $c$ is a root of $p(x)$.
3. Note in particular $c^3+c+1=0$.  Hence $c^3=-c-1=c+1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2$.
4. The addition and multiplication tables of these eight elements are given below.

Addition table:
\begin{array}{ c| c c c c c c c c }
    +     & 0       & 1         & x       & x^2     & 1+x     & 1+x^2   & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2 \\ \hline
    0     & 0       & 1         & x       & x^2     & 1+x     & 1+x^2   & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2 \\
    1     & 1       & 0         & 1+x     & 1+x^2   & x       & x^2     & 1+x+x^2 & x+x^2   \\
    x     & x       & 1+x       & 0       & x+x^2   & 1       & 1+x+x^2 & x^2     & 1+x^2   \\
    x^2   & x^2     & 1+x^2     & x+x^2   & 0       & 1+x+x^2 & 1       & x       & 1+x     \\
    1+x   & 1+x     & x         & 1       & 1+x+x^2 & 0       & x+x^2   & 1+x^2   & x^2     \\
    1+x^2 & 1+x^2   & x^2       & 1+x+x^2 & 1       & x+x^2   & 0       & 1+x     & x       \\
    x+x^2 & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2   & x^2     & x       & 1+x^2   & 1+x     & 0       & 1       \\
  1+x+x^2 & 1+x+x^2 & x+x^2     & 1+x^2   & 1+x     & x^2     & x       & 1       & 0
\end{array}

Multiplication table:

\begin{array}{ c | c c c c c c c c }
 *      & 0 & 1       & x       & x^2     & 1+x     & 1+x^2   & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2  \\ \hline
 0      & 0 & 0       & 0       & 0       & 0       & 0       & 0       & 0        \\
 1      & 0 & 1       & x       & x^2     & 1+x     & 1+x^2   & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2  \\
 x      & 0 & x       & x^2     & 1+x     & x+x^2   & 1       & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x^2    \\
 x^2    & 0 & x^2     & 1+x     & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2 & x       & 1+x^2   & 1        \\
 1+x    & 0 & 1+x     & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x^2   & x^2     & 1       & x        \\
 1+x^2  & 0 & 1+x^2   & 1       & x       & x^2     & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x     & x+x^2    \\
 x+x^2  & 0 & x+x^2   & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x^2   & 1       & 1+x     & x       & x^2      \\
  1+x+x^2  & 0 & 1+x+x^2 & 1+x^2   & 1       & x       & x+x^2   & x^2     & 1+x
\end{array}

Is this correct?

Comment: Under 3. it should read modulo $\mathbb{Z}_2$ not "in". Looks ok, but I haven't checked the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris Custer said, this is just a $3$-dimensional vector space with basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, so yes, there are $2^3=8$ elements that you listed.

Addition is just the usual componentwise addition (mod $2$, of course).

For multiplication, you can make your life easier than doing the whole table. Since $x^3 = -x-1 = x + 1$ and $x^4 = x^3\cdot x = x^2+x$, we have

\begin{align}
\left(a+b x+c x^2\right) & \left(d+e x+f x^2\right)\\ & =a d + (b d + a e) x + (c d + b e + a f) x^2 + (c e + b f) x^3 + 
 c f x^4\\
&= a d + c e + 
 b f + (b d + a e + c e + b f + c f) x + (c d + b e + a f + c f) x^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting.  As far as the book goes, we have not ventured into vector space at this point, and the primary focus is on extensions of fields.  Good to preview how things are inter-related.

Comment: @hchar, every field extension $K$ of $k$ is a vector space over $k$ immediately. You can add elements in $K$ since it's field, and you can multiply them by scalars from $k$, since it's extension. For example, $\mathbb C$ is $2$-dimensional space over $\mathbb R$ with basis $\{1,i\}$, which you know. $\mathbb R$ is infinite dimensional space over $\mathbb Q$, since there are transcedental numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This looks right.  It's a $3$-dimensional $\Bbb Z_2$ vector space.